# parse possible errors when converting files to JSON

Tags: json, converters, analytics

I'm about to complete a tutorial project - a web service for converting files of various extensions to JSON. And I need to describe the errors that the user may encounter. For example, the file exceeds a certain memory limit, etc. Help, please, deal with more non-trivial errors.

What was written by me:
bad internet connection,
file does not open,
memory limit exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- InvalidFileType: Assuming your app only handles certain input file types, this would be when the user attempts to upload an unsupported one.
- FileSizeExceededError: When the file exceeds your limit.
- NullFileError: Uploaded file contains no data.
- FileUploadError: Something went wrong during the file upload process.
- FileReadError: The file might not follow the specification for the filetype.
- InvalidFileEncodingError: The file's encoding isn't supported.
- ConversionError: There was an error during the conversion process.
- UnsupportedFeatureError: If the file contains a feature or structure that isn't supported by your app.
- RateLimitExceededError: User is attempting to convert too many files per a specific timeframe
- Any number of user errors, perhaps the user has signed up, but they need to be verified or another criteria.